# All Stack Exchange data dumps

Tags: support, data-dump

The original ClearBits link to the September 2011 data dump has broken. How can I access it and other previous data dumps? The Internet Archive only has [the latest one](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

Answer (score 84):

Here are the torrents for each data dump release. The contents may or may not be available.

### Stack Exchange Network Data Dumps

```
Release          BitTorrent Infohash and Magnet Link
```

```
2009 May         ea45080eab61ab465f647e6366f775bf25f69a61  in Internet Archive
2009 June        68d22f0f856ca5056e009ac53597a66c0cb03068  in Internet Archive
2009 July        2dca38c1c9724462ad4cedb42a1569805ab80f0c  in Internet Archive
2009 August      d348861b6d72c280f299e03fe9f9e8f3258eff19  in Internet Archive
2009 …rerelease  f6ec47fba06823e22ede500511ab7c60ceddd91d  in Internet Archive
2009 September   395bb1a89607fa05a9774bd7683eb3b6052989f7  in Internet Archive
2009 October     61b882a518f21344ca82d4632f89a1dcafcbd3ed  in Internet Archive
2009 November    107f674c9b6a481eef7c81910228bc773246035b  in Internet Archive
2009 December    11a2a48f204497f4222ff5edaf790f1d38a651fe  in Internet Archive
2010 January     5127f67fb6099d322b6467bd85a1363fe8a73c3f  in Internet Archive
2010 February    cec670fa3c54bf8403bef2d0801a6f9478fb2c68  in Internet Archive
2010 March       a790a8ab30f91c344c5b400579acd5643b2bb25c  in Internet Archive
2010 April       53adea3f9acb1972201f059604c4bdad5e3e0a8c  in Internet Archive
2010 May         f318086e65e7873d1a44de07e6d3ef4de0da0004  in Internet Archive
2010 June        2c802d003e59f84776a40b361584e1125d4eb877  in Internet Archive
2010 July        fe29a5a7278960002cae679024f0175db3e470f1  in Internet Archive
2010 August      53c3bf7f3b2ba1675acf3ac21bbaf84c63ca94c7  in Internet Archive
2010 September   8f5c7a0bac4f5ee27b7cd7a1c179ba0ba66eb847  in Internet Archive
2010 October     b549412a5e8aa70421756f0348f8063638994114  in Internet Archive
2010 November    f26b0ae2b975254676a02bdfb0fd4b7f6f78b951  in Internet Archive
2011 January     16e7c2867f7b5be3d7dbe7c3f707601b16c5f2c5  in Internet Archive
2011 April       ec636f7edc262053429653edfdf47e806f14e72f  in Internet Archive
2011 June        cdb37ea243e09fcaf54e6b7f19764765a706724c  in Internet Archive
2011 September   64d052f755e01d1c947848ad3d22180476a71a94  in Internet Archive
2011 December    77ccfd3451c442590bf5bd940362a121a16ee5a3
2011 …part 2     ccb07610f73f994b15399acdd507778dce964111
2011 …part 3     de13c16eb98bc8e95a77ed7e0ff6953d60bf90ba
2012 April       c0ecc66e8f1d630cbcd39bf523b3381a7779daa3
2012 August      ecf5ec6d0a2a3a5b582b1ef684a5fe4552ff1c8b
2012 …part 2     b06fff722ce06520b59a9db72cab9f7d008ff8c3
2013 March       47e02c81368acd9fa0f884439c00fa8439ef971f
2013 September   c472a68f39cd333816098e53ae353e8d90c3e9d3
2014 January     cc28f62bb9eb1da79ca2a782960f86f64d8ceb87
2014 May         3aed037c4c0a73d2f3eb244b99c1cd842bc88142
2014 September   b1a458cba5af9525d4012c20f9c51b35a15f0984
2015 March       0ea39049afdbaaea255ca1d0af662e2a0d503098
2016 March       57ceb5ac3e22cbf4e4de8b94f9814e809f0765bb
2016 June        e1a5e02efb60d9514c8822b1f9d3e605436caac9
2016 September   be15f50878cb77028b119a9f922f02e439481030
2016 December    fd86cb81c9ab08bd3a0969d4c700555ec7814328
2017 March       586eebe6f3c19db48a5ea471579b96d3bd3ba6e3
2017 June        fa38c0e9bbbb060927a7a7ca1f9325aa98466e1f
2017 December    e73b7025a2af72124ae49d184fa3e8cec3f66016
2018 March       4ad8edb2e0781d381d110778036703da988de71a  in Internet Archive
2018 June        8e6a46cc6290ee3dc93cec299b6e28b7ee2f3228
2018 September   bddb28e2bc5fecdc2acf83c76e7941797fc98b2e
2018 December    d1623b9edd9ee6787fdb614299d14baa94e24d80
2019 March       f8b00f75393b2fca5e8796e48cfe89c2f0536fa2
2019 June        593cf931e968c608f953b3b62d513d2365d68aa2
2019 September   8cec36af3037f78e793057eeb38b684048d043de
2019 December    fd11cc265a7964b42ac80f21c216420372c9cada
2020 March       a6266395a2bb85fecde76ee8324bc05827554e81
2020 June        daceb39faefc3f797005488f56e3b01c57c5af91
2020 September   a321f0dfa7d037db155590fa89ff118271d07a85
2020 December    3fa542ce4c9322df301e2c89a1d9c2bc87541015
2021 March       03ae768efe49a064e3b7fe5bb554203258383689  in Internet Archive
2021 June        ee64468a824040067d468d57f51e63ae9cf1aaa6  in Internet Archive
2021 September   27689c6b23a5b606987114abc3e9ba2668f93755  in Internet Archive
2021 December    677a281a1b9bcbc4684f1f5659db0e6de0f1488e  in Internet Archive
2022 March       5854d890b3c845b75b1c67e96eecbdc38d6db883  in Internet Archive
2022 June        8225cdd03712ddf0c3f0261bf982fc21d7647221  in Internet Archive
2022 October     1c65c4a7ccfdd77bc542d7220a28b99893c6fa3d  in Internet Archive
2022 December    b369adf8a6da002537e8b0c49e187448e0138281  in Internet Archive
2023 March       263d19f9188a146b150648cd1975820f3ebbd38e  in Internet Archive
2023 June        93d9b232af49082b59693e6e07f6d05ea8e99ec8  in Internet Archive
2023 September   d884b3a9235ca1196f0646ad0cdcb17b201bc3cc  in Internet Archive
2023 December    414f55d7635a4c7fbe02c90c7d79b80d9046d4f2  in Internet Archive
2024 March       5a3d9b0c0855056a5ef6e90d9766c3005145c979  in Internet Archive
2024 April       ab12faaecac0918b0ca00bff7cb9d9eafab8c01e
```

### Other Data Dumps

```
Release          BitTorrent Infohash and Download Link
```

```
Teams Beta       49f231796a07e783782ddc38fc750530f289514b  in Internet Archive
Docs Beta        ea3383630fa76399d135856f030aee0177bebd8a  in Internet Archive
```

```js
// Generates Stack Exchange Network Data Dumps table above

class Release {
  constructor(infohash, year, month, announcement = null, nameSuffix = '', iaItemName = null) {
    this.infohash = infohash;
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.announcement = announcement;
    this.nameSuffix = nameSuffix;
    this.iaItemName = iaItemName;
  }
}

const releases = [
  new Release(
    'ea45080eab61ab465f647e6366f775bf25f69a61', 2009, "May",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20090611145537/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump',
    '', 'stackexchange-ea45080eab61ab465f647e6366f775bf25f69a61'
  ), new Release(
    '68d22f0f856ca5056e009ac53597a66c0cb03068', 2009, "June",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20090611145537/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump',
    '', 'stackexchange-68d22f0f856ca5056e009ac53597a66c0cb03068'
  ), new Release(
    '2dca38c1c9724462ad4cedb42a1569805ab80f0c', 2009, "July",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20090709135537/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/creative-commons-data-dump-july-09/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    'd348861b6d72c280f299e03fe9f9e8f3258eff19', 2009, "August",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20100723003527/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/creative-commons-data-dump-aug-09/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    'f6ec47fba06823e22ede500511ab7c60ceddd91d', 2009, "August",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20100723003527/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/creative-commons-data-dump-aug-09/',
    "rerelease", 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    '395bb1a89607fa05a9774bd7683eb3b6052989f7', 2009, "September",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20091107195235/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-09/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    '61b882a518f21344ca82d4632f89a1dcafcbd3ed', 2009, "October",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20091014190329/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/creative-commons-data-dump-oct-09',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    '107f674c9b6a481eef7c81910228bc773246035b', 2009, "November",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20101114080034/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/creative-commons-data-dump-nov-09/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    '11a2a48f204497f4222ff5edaf790f1d38a651fe', 2009, "December",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20100308032107/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/creative-commons-data-dump-dec-09/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    '5127f67fb6099d322b6467bd85a1363fe8a73c3f', 2010, "January",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20101127005212/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/creative-commons-data-dump-jan-10',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    'cec670fa3c54bf8403bef2d0801a6f9478fb2c68', 2010, "February",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20100408002215/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/02/creative-commons-data-dump-feb-10/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    'a790a8ab30f91c344c5b400579acd5643b2bb25c', 2010, "March",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20100926214909/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/creative-commons-data-dump-mar-10/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    '53adea3f9acb1972201f059604c4bdad5e3e0a8c', 2010, "April",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20100812014035/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/creative-commons-data-dump-apr-10/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    'f318086e65e7873d1a44de07e6d3ef4de0da0004', 2010, "May",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20101104093225/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/creative-commons-data-dump-may-10/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    '2c802d003e59f84776a40b361584e1125d4eb877', 2010, "June",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20101212205817/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/creative-commons-data-dump-jun-10/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    'fe29a5a7278960002cae679024f0175db3e470f1', 2010, "July",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20101108003200/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/creative-commons-data-dump-jul-10/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    '53c3bf7f3b2ba1675acf3ac21bbaf84c63ca94c7', 2010, "August",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20101012054011/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/creative-commons-data-dump-aug-10/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    '8f5c7a0bac4f5ee27b7cd7a1c179ba0ba66eb847', 2010, "September",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20101109045417/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sept-10/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    'b549412a5e8aa70421756f0348f8063638994114', 2010, "October",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20101113193850/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/creative-commons-data-dump-oct-10',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    'f26b0ae2b975254676a02bdfb0fd4b7f6f78b951', 2010, "November",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20101203005658/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/creative-commons-data-dump-nov-10/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    '16e7c2867f7b5be3d7dbe7c3f707601b16c5f2c5', 2011, "January",
    'https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/creative-commons-data-dump-jan-11/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    'ec636f7edc262053429653edfdf47e806f14e72f', 2011, "April",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20110410104736/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/creative-commons-data-dump-apr-11/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    'cdb37ea243e09fcaf54e6b7f19764765a706724c', 2011, "June",
    'https://liveweb.archive.org/web/20110914082314/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/creative-commons-data-dump-jun-11/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    '64d052f755e01d1c947848ad3d22180476a71a94', 2011, "September",
    'https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/',
    '', 'StackExchange2009-2011',
  ), new Release(
    '77ccfd3451c442590bf5bd940362a121a16ee5a3', 2011, "December",
    'https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116369/several-sites-are-missing-from-the-december-2011-data-dump'
  ), new Release(
    'ccb07610f73f994b15399acdd507778dce964111', 2011, "December",
    'https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116369/several-sites-are-missing-from-the-december-2011-data-dump',
    "part 2"
  ), new Release(
    'de13c16eb98bc8e95a77ed7e0ff6953d60bf90ba', 2011, "December",
    'https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116369/several-sites-are-missing-from-the-december-2011-data-dump',
    "part 3"
  ), new Release(
    'c0ecc66e8f1d630cbcd39bf523b3381a7779daa3', 2012, "April"
  ), new Release(
    'ecf5ec6d0a2a3a5b582b1ef684a5fe4552ff1c8b', 2012, "August",
    'https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143709/are-all-the-meta-sites-intended-to-be-included-in-the-data-dump'
  ), new Release(
    'b06fff722ce06520b59a9db72cab9f7d008ff8c3', 2012, "August",
    'https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143709/are-all-the-meta-sites-intended-to-be-included-in-the-data-dump',
    "part 2"
  ), new Release(
    '47e02c81368acd9fa0f884439c00fa8439ef971f', 2013, "March"
  ), new Release(
    'c472a68f39cd333816098e53ae353e8d90c3e9d3', 2013, "September"
  ), new Release(
    'cc28f62bb9eb1da79ca2a782960f86f64d8ceb87', 2014, "January",
    'https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/'
  ), new Release(
    '3aed037c4c0a73d2f3eb244b99c1cd842bc88142', 2014, "May"
  ), new Release(
    'b1a458cba5af9525d4012c20f9c51b35a15f0984', 2014, "September",
    'https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240139/stack-exchange-september-2014-data-dump-is-available'
  ), new Release(
    '0ea39049afdbaaea255ca1d0af662e2a0d503098', 2015, "March"
  ), new Release(
    '57ceb5ac3e22cbf4e4de8b94f9814e809f0765bb', 2016, "March"
  ), new Release(
    'e1a5e02efb60d9514c8822b1f9d3e605436caac9', 2016, "June"
  ), new Release(
    'be15f50878cb77028b119a9f922f02e439481030', 2016, "September"
  ), new Release(
    'fd86cb81c9ab08bd3a0969d4c700555ec7814328', 2016, "December"
  ), new Release(
    '586eebe6f3c19db48a5ea471579b96d3bd3ba6e3', 2017, "March"
  ), new Release(
    'fa38c0e9bbbb060927a7a7ca1f9325aa98466e1f', 2017, "June"
  ), new Release(
    'e73b7025a2af72124ae49d184fa3e8cec3f66016', 2017, "December",
    'https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302786/stack-exchange-data-dump-no-longer-available-via-bittorrent-since-june-2017/'
  ), new Release(
    '4ad8edb2e0781d381d110778036703da988de71a', 2018, "March",
    '', '', 'stackexchange-snapshot-2018-03-14'
  ), new Release(
    '8e6a46cc6290ee3dc93cec299b6e28b7ee2f3228', 2018, "June",
  ), new Release(
    'bddb28e2bc5fecdc2acf83c76e7941797fc98b2e', 2018, "September",
  ), new Release(
    'd1623b9edd9ee6787fdb614299d14baa94e24d80', 2018, "December"
  ), new Release(
    'f8b00f75393b2fca5e8796e48cfe89c2f0536fa2', 2019, "March"
  ), new Release(
    '593cf931e968c608f953b3b62d513d2365d68aa2', 2019, "June"
  ), new Release(
    '8cec36af3037f78e793057eeb38b684048d043de', 2019, "September"
  ), new Release(
    'fd11cc265a7964b42ac80f21c216420372c9cada', 2019, "December"
  ), new Release(
    'a6266395a2bb85fecde76ee8324bc05827554e81', 2020, "March"
  ), new Release(
    'daceb39faefc3f797005488f56e3b01c57c5af91', 2020, "June"
  ), new Release(
    'a321f0dfa7d037db155590fa89ff118271d07a85', 2020, "September"
  ), new Release(
    '3fa542ce4c9322df301e2c89a1d9c2bc87541015', 2020, "December"
  ), new Release(
    '03ae768efe49a064e3b7fe5bb554203258383689', 2021, "March",
    '', '', 'stackexchange_20210301'
  ), new Release(
    'ee64468a824040067d468d57f51e63ae9cf1aaa6', 2021, "June",
    '', '', 'stackexchange_20210607'
  ), new Release(
    '27689c6b23a5b606987114abc3e9ba2668f93755', 2021, "September",
    "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369502/data-dump-in-the-internet-archive-is-no-longer-available-what-has-happened#comment1233074_369521", '',
    'stackexchange_20210907'
  ), new Release(
    '677a281a1b9bcbc4684f1f5659db0e6de0f1488e', 2021, "December",
    '', '', 'stackexchange_20211206',
  ), new Release(
    '5854d890b3c845b75b1c67e96eecbdc38d6db883', 2022, "March",
    "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377171/waiting-for-march-2022-dump/",
    '', 'stackexchange_20220307',
  ), new Release(
    '8225cdd03712ddf0c3f0261bf982fc21d7647221', 2022, "June",
    '', '', 'stackexchange_20220606'
  ), new Release(
    '1c65c4a7ccfdd77bc542d7220a28b99893c6fa3d', 2022, "October",
    '', '', 'stackexchange_20221005'
  ), new Release(
    'b369adf8a6da002537e8b0c49e187448e0138281', 2022, "December",
    '', '', 'stackexchange_20221206'
  ), new Release(
    '263d19f9188a146b150648cd1975820f3ebbd38e', 2023, "March",
    '', '', 'stackexchange_20230308'
  ), new Release(
    '93d9b232af49082b59693e6e07f6d05ea8e99ec8', 2023, "June",
    'https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389922/june-2023-data-dump-is-missing/390200#390200',
    '', 'stackexchange_20230614'
  ), new Release(
    'd884b3a9235ca1196f0646ad0cdcb17b201bc3cc', 2023, "September",
    'https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392720/possible-delay-in-data-dump-release-now-targeting-september-5th',
    '', 'stackexchange_20230912'
  ), new Release(
    '414f55d7635a4c7fbe02c90c7d79b80d9046d4f2', 2023, "December",
    'https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395197/delay-in-data-dump-release',
    '', 'stackexchange_20231208'
  ), new Release(
    '5a3d9b0c0855056a5ef6e90d9766c3005145c979', 2024, "March",
    'https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396597/data-dumps-releases-timeline-updates-and-clarification',
    '', 'stackexchange_20240305'
  ),  new Release(
    'ab12faaecac0918b0ca00bff7cb9d9eafab8c01e', 2024, "April",
    'https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/398606'
  ), 
];

const pad = (x, length) => {
  let s = String(x);
  while (s.length < length) s += ' ';
  return s;
};

const lines = [];

lines.push(`<pre><code><b>Release          BitTorrent Infohash and Magnet Link</b></code></pre><pre><code>`);

for (const r of releases) {
  const label = !r.nameSuffix ? `${pad(r.year, 4)} ${pad(r.month)}` : r.year + ' …' + r.nameSuffix;
  const dn = `${r.month} ${r.year} Stack Exchange Data Dump${r.nameSuffix ? ' (' + r.nameSuffix + ')' : ''}`;
  let labelCode =
    r.announcement ? `<a href="${r.announcement}">${label}</a>` : label;
  for (let i = label.length; i < 16; i++) {
    labelCode += ' ';
  }
  // We use a redirect at https://dash.deno.com/playground/mag
  // because stack exchange doesn't allow direct magnet links
  // in post bodies.
  const download = `https://mag.deno.dev/magnet:?xt=urn:btih:${r.infohash}&dn=${encodeURIComponent(dn)}`;
  if (r.infohash) {
    lines.push(`${labelCode} <a href="${download}">${pad(r.infohash, 20)}</a>`);
  } else {
    lines.push(`${labelCode} <i>${"torrent unknown".padEnd(40)}</i>`)
  }
  if (r.iaItemName) {
    lines.push(`  <a href="https://archive.org/download/${r.iaItemName}">in Internet Archive</a>`);
  }
  lines.push('\n');
}

lines.push(`</code></pre>`);
const generated = lines.join('')

const source = document.createElement('pre');
source.textContent = generated;
source.style.userSelect = 'all';
document.body.appendChild(source);

const hr = document.createElement('hr');
document.body.appendChild(hr);

const preview = document.createElement('div');
preview.innerHTML = generated;
document.body.appendChild(preview);
```

The list above omits some releases which had errors and were immediately replaced.

Comment: Shameless plug: if anybody is curious, I have recently written [a Stack Overflow answer explaining how BitTorrent magnet links work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22240583/1114).

Comment: I need a StackOverflow Data Dump in which MD5 e-mail checksum are visible. Can you confirm that a kind of this is still availble? Thanks :)

Comment: @gios91 Unfortunately for that use case, the email hashes haven't been [included since either the January 2014 or March 2013 dump](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221032/134300) (I'm not sure which). As this change was made to increase privacy, it's unlikely to ever be changed back. If you have an academic use intended for it, and affiliations with an academic institution, I think Stack Exchange might provide more complete dumps under an NDA, but I don't remember where I read that, so I can't confirm right now.

Comment: It looks like there Internet Archive's public log files include the infohashes of all generated torrents. [You can see one here](https://catalogd.archive.org/log/606357701). So that should allow this list to be maintained even if some updates are missed at the time.

Comment: "The contents may or may not be available." -> [Hosting all Stack Exchange data dumps on archive.org](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306316/178179)

Comment: Do we know if the new dump is complete?

Comment: @Nemo please define "complete"? What are you missing?

Comment: @rene That's my question: "what are we missing?" We don't know until someone tests. A more recent update is at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342634/248268

Answer (score 25):

The older dumps from 2009 to 2011 are available here:

https://tejp.de/files/so/dbdump ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/StackExchange2009-2011))

Comment: Just curious - who is hosting these?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I am :)

Answer (score 3):

Here are the data after December 2017

https://empirical-software.engineering/sotorrent/

Comment: This only contains StackOverflow data.