# Access to earlier data dumps (Looking for May 2014 data dump)

Tags: support, data-dump

The latest September 2014 Stack Exchange data dump is available at https://archive.org/details/stackexchange.

I am interested in **previous** data dumps, and in May 2014 data dump (the one that was published before the September one) in particular.

Is it possible to get the torrent file for that dump? Is it still available?

**UPDATE: Is there anyone who has a torrent for the May 2014 dump?**

Comment: I am not looking for the dump for previous years shared via ClearBits listed in the linked post, but for a torrent for the May 2014 dump which was published on archive.org.

Answer (score 3):

archive.org would have changed the torrent file they host to a new one when we uploaded the updated files.

If they don't publish the old torrent file, your only recourse is to find that file and hope it has seeders - or if someone sees this question, perhaps they have the dump which they can share.

This is true for all the dumps that were originally hosted on clearbits - see [All Stack Exchange data dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224873/stack-exchange-data-dumps-for-previous-years).