# Graph of the views

Tags: discussion, statistics

I searched the questions on the site, but none came close to what I imagined.

I would like to know if it is possible to see a graph of the views that any page over a certain period.

For example, how many times has this page been viewed today, showing a graph of the last 24 hours.

Comment: Pretty certain that this sort of information is not public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to see this. Even the 25k [site analytics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) tools are for the entire site, not individual pages. Also, SEDE and the dumps don't have timestamped view info.

You have two options:

1. You can download [all of the past data dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224873/all-stack-exchange-data-dumps) and compare, but those are only dumped quarterly.
2. You can write a tool to periodically [query the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=296411&filter=!9al1517Pw&site=meta&run=true), or manually check the API or [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/675763) (Stack Exchange Data Explorer) every so often, to keep track and generate a graph over time, but of course this won't give you historical data before you start logging. The API is real time, and SEDE is updated weekly.

Other than that, unfortunately, no, that info is not public.