# Stack Exchange Data Dump no longer available via BitTorrent (since June 2017)

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-dump

[The Data Dump on Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) was last updated a month ago, but the torrent version is not available. In fact, no torrent has been made available for any release since June (see [my index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224922/134300)), when the Stack Exchange Archive entry was accidentally marked as spam.

Stack Overflow should consider reaching out to the Archive to see if this can be fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Haney](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/262550/haney) reached out to Jeff Kaplan at the Internet Archive, and the torrent has been restored:

```
https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackexchange_archive.torrent
```

```
magnet:
?xt=urn:btih:e73b7025a2af72124ae49d184fa3e8cec3f66016
&dn=stackexchange
&tr=http%3A%2F%2Fbt1.archive.org%3A6969%2Fannounce
&tr=http%3A%2F%2Fbt2.archive.org%3A6969%2Fannounce
&ws=https%3A%2F%2Farchive.org%2Fdownload%2F
&ws=http%3A%2F%2Fia600801.us.archive.org%2F23%2Fitems%2F
&ws=http%3A%2F%2Fia800801.us.archive.org%2F23%2Fitems%2F
```

Comment: I get this message: *"Requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker."* However, download with the `ia` python module works, although it requires registration to the archive.org .