# When will the next Stack Exchange datadump be on Archive.org?

Tags: discussion, support

Assuming that the datadump of StackExchange is released quarterly, will the next datadump be on Archive.org at the 1st of March? Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: It looks like an irregular interval: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224873/all-stack-exchange-data-dumps/224922#224922 but March would be good bet.

Comment: April of 2018 ..