# Data Dump in the Internet Archive is no longer available. What has happened?

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-dump, archive

## The context

I'm getting the following (see screenshot below) when visiting the Stack Exchange Data Dump in the Internet Archive. Here's the [URL](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

[image: error message shown when attempting to access the data dump]

> This item is no longer available.
>
> Items may be taken down for various reasons, including by decision of the uploader or due to a violation of our Terms of Use

Because the data dump is no longer available, it is not listed in the  list of items uploaded by Stack Exchange in the Internet Archive (see screenshot below). Here's the [URL](https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Stack+Exchange%2C+Inc.%22).

[image: list of items uploaded by Stack Exchange in archive.org. The data dump is not present]

## The question

Why is the data dump no longer available in the Internet Archive?

Comment: Checking a link over at SO I got a similar message, prefixed with this: "The item you have requested has a problem with one or more of the metadata files that describe it, which prevents us from displaying this page." - maybe there was a problem with the upload.

Comment: Well... yikes... Apparently the Internet Archive detected "malware" in our Monero dump and automatically removed it from their servers. Someone will look into it.

Comment: I’m aware of this. I was working on the upload today and it was pulled. I have reached out to them and am working to get it resolved. Unfortunately it’s a holiday here in the US so I don’t think I’ll hear anything today.

Comment: Cross-post at Monero Meta: [What content from this site was detected as "malware" in the data dump?](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222/what-content-from-this-site-was-detected-as-malware-in-the-data-dump) cc @Taryn

Comment: @animuson does it mean full SE network might have malware?

Answer (score 18):

This has been resolved for now. There is an issue with the new data dump for Monero that I'll be investigating and correcting - or I should say attempting to correct. We've had this issue with Monero before and just didn't upload the file as we couldn't get around the issue.

I'll get back to uploading the rest of the latest data dump now.

Comment: Great that the other sites are fixed. Would the Internet Archive be able to help troubleshoot what post(s) cause their scanner to reject the upload. Or is your only option to upload chuncks of the file and to see what part fails?

Comment: @Luuklag We know what it is, there is some post(s) somewhere on Monero that trips all the virus scans. Each time we're attempted to find the issue, we end up with more alerts on the file...so it's like finding a needle in the haystack. We had this issue before and made the decision to skip Monero in the dump. It will probably happen again. We were directed to [this](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/cd67c172fd1dd60dfb866bd9b8de1f8790b0dfd28bd8ee83adaee79f4da9a2aa/detection/f-cd67c172fd1dd60dfb866bd9b8de1f8790b0dfd28bd8ee83adaee79f4da9a2aa-1630936210).

Comment: I was thinking that pergaos some invested Monero users could aid in this quest of epic proportions. If there is a way to manually scan these posts, then the offending post(s) could perhaps be found and removed from the database by you or one of your colleagues.

Comment: @Luuklag The complexity comes in with the fact that we're not uploading malware. The post(s) have a link to something which is being interpreted as a virus and it gets flagged. In the past when we've attempted to resolve it, we have ended up with more things being flagged as malware. Honestly, it's not an easy fix

Comment: I don't understand why failing to upload one file out of 150+ cause ALL files to be unavailable though. Unless I miss something basic here? Thanks for the quick handling!

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 It's in a single job, so it pulls everything.