# Where has the Stack Exchange official dump gone? archive.org/details/stackexchange

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, data-dump, archive

Why do I see this message after I only download *StackOverflow-Posts.7z*?

I have tried to use a VPN, but I receive the same error message:

> This item is no longer available.
>
> Items may be taken down for various reasons, including by decision of
> the uploader or due to a violation of our Terms of Use.

Comment: See [Error while downloading all Stack Exchange data dumps](/q/376917/289905) and [Waiting for March 2022 dump](/q/377171/289905).

Comment: Looks like we uploaded a new dump and [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369502/data-dump-in-the-internet-archive-is-no-longer-available-what-has-happened) popped up again, this time on Reverse Engineering SE.

Comment: @animuson Do you have a VirusTotal link like last time? that might help finding the issue

Comment: I made a post on RE.meta: [Database dump of this site is detected as malware](https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/416/database-dump-of-this-site-is-detected-as-malware)

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you guys. Is https://archive.org/details/stackexchange is only official releases for dump files?

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277952/269301) lists all dumps.

Comment: [This blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/01/23/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/) explains a couple of things as well.

Comment: Be patient, [they're working on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377216/269301).