# Error while downloading all Stack Exchange data dumps

Tags: support, data-dump

I’m working on the analysis and prediction of deletion questions in the Stack Overflow project. By comparing different data sets, I can retrieve all the deleted questions by using data dumps obtained from Stack Overflow.

Due to broken links, I cannot download previous data dumps from Clearbits. I found the magnet links to all the data dumps in the question: [All Stack Exchange data dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224873). When I tried to download the dumps using hash information, only the dumps up to 2011 were able to download, and the rest kept loading as torrents. The majority of the files status in the dumps till 2011 were showing as errors.

I was not able to locate the [data dumps on archive.org](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) as each dump has a different name.

Could someone point me to a place where I can download all the data dumps?

Comment: Sadly it's one big mess since it was never really official. Former employee took it on himself as personal project to upload the dumps, but as a single person can't be expected to maintain it. (I *think* officially, SE maintains only the latest data dump, changing host sometimes)

Comment: Why are different names a problem?

Comment: As they are having different naming conventions for each data dumps it’s difficult to search in the archive.