# How can I get notified about released Stack Exchange dumps?

Tags: support, data-dump

I am interested in being notified when a new data dump is published [on the internet archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). I want to find some way to be automatically notified - ideally an RSS feed, but an email or something else that can be followed easily would work. I do not need *immediate* notification, as in within seconds or minutes. A day or two would also be OK. Maybe a week at most.

I am aware of but **not looking for** [All Stack Exchange data dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224873/all-stack-exchange-data-dumps)

Comment: As someone who wants to seed the current datadump (even if I don't have the space/time for the old ones) - there's a certain value in updates of updates so I can dump the old dump and seed the new one

Comment: I feel like the "upload is complete" notification would have to come from Archive, since _we_ don't even know when the files are all made available (we know when they've all been _uploaded_, but before they appear in our directory and available to you, they are subject to processing on their side that has been ... unpredictable). I've been refreshing [a page like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJOip.png).

Comment: And when [these changes Slate mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392720/possible-delay-in-data-dump-release-now-targeting-september-5th#comment1313919_392720) get implemented - hopefully before the December data dump - we'll have even less direct insight into "final state."

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes, something from archive.org would be great. However, I've not found a way to get some sort of update from there. Maybe there is one I don't know of. Or maybe there is some other channel that somebody knows of. It's why I asked the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if anything exists there either (or a channel to ask). But a simple crawler/script could parse [this page](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and notify you when the date changes (which is something we do manually when we determine that the upload is "ready") or [this page](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange) (searching for `{this month 3 letters english}-{this year}` which means a new one has at least started). I did this on 9/9 in spite of one file being "parked" - waiting on Archive to determine what file that even is, since the log I have access to is cryptic.

Comment: One thing we could potentially do, and note that this isn't a promise or a commitment to do it, just floating an idea: When we know that the data dump is ready, we could post here with tags announcement / featured / data-dump, which then userscripts / rss here could help sort you out. This would still be subject to the delay of us knowing and confirming that the dump is ready. And it would require a bit of coordination on our side, but not crazy, that would add to that delay.

Comment: Posting as a comment since I'm not entirely sure this is an answer: can't you just use the archive.org rss per subject: https://archive.org/services/collection-rss.php?query=subject:%22Stack%20Exchange%20Data%20Dump%22?

Comment: @ErikA But I think that demonstrates part of the problem: that feed doesn't (yet) have the newest dump listed.

Comment: @ErikA I tried the archive.org RSS feed but for some reason I wasn't getting any results. I must have used the parameters for it wrong. I was going to look more into it later. Still as Aaron noted - it doesn't have the 09-09 dump yet. I don't know how long it takes to update. If it's, say, ~5 days it might be OK.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't show up in the feed because the new dump isn't fully updated yet? The archive page indicates it's "currently being modified/updated", and despite the topic showing "Stack Exchange Data Dump - 2023-09-09", the [metadata file in the dump](https://dn902605.us.archive.org/0/items/stackexchange/stackexchange_meta.xml) still indicates the old "2023-06-14" date.

Comment: @zcoop98 where can I see the "currently being modified/updated" status?

Comment: @VLAZ that specific message is a banner that appears on the archive page, I thought only when the metadata file was being updated, but it has been removed now, even though I am still waiting on one file and the metadata file is still showing the June date. I wish I understood all of the mechanics but the archive definitely works in mysterious ways. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @VLAZ [it has returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0xB5.png).

Comment: Well, as of this morning, [_this_ data dump appears complete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392947/165455). I know it's not the automated notification you want, but it's the best I can do for now. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I will take the Aarontomated notification :P I hope in the future I wouldn't need staff to notify me. The RSS feed is not updated yet but maybe that is also a matter of time. If so, it would be a good enough approach.

Comment: Aarontomation: The current data dump was completed yesterday.