# Shifting the data dump schedule: A proposal

Tags: discussion, data-dump

My colleague Rosie [recently announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396597/165455) that, because of our difficulties predictably getting data dump files to the Internet Archive<sup>[[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395197/165455),[[2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392720/165455)</sup>, we are setting more realistic expectations for completing that process.

A [comment on that post from Fabio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396597/data-dumps-releases-timeline-updates-and-clarification?cb=1#comment1326694_396597) made us consider that it is confusing to have a quarterly data dump for, say, Q1 released in early March - but, because of how time works, couldn’t possibly include all of the data for Q1.

“First weekend of the last month of the quarter” has been the publication schedule for as long as I can remember, but it doesn't have to stay that way.

### Proposal

We huddled and decided that it would be beneficial to offer you a chance to help us fix that, too, as a part of this change. We've [already delivered the data dump for this month](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), and propose that:

- **We produce a new dump for all of Q1**
  Delivered sometime in April, including data up to the end of March (or later).
- **We then resume a quarterly schedule**
  Producing dumps in July (for Q2), October (for Q3), and January (for Q4).

### Background

The dumps are produced after the Data Explorer refresh on the first of the month and contain, at a *minimum*, data up until just before midnight on the last day of the previous month. Sometimes there are a few extra days, depending on when generation starts and, because they run sequentially, they can't cut off exactly at midnight.

### New schedule

With this proposal, the new schedule would look like this:

| Year/Q | Generation started by | Contains data through | Delivery by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024 Q2 | July 7th, 2024 | June 30th, 2024 | July 31st, 2024 |
| 2024 Q3 | October 6th, 2024 | September 30th, 2024 | October 31st, 2024 |
| 2024 Q4 | January 5th, 2025 | December 31st, 2024 | January 31st, 2025 |
| 2025 Q1 | April 6th, 2025 | March 31st, 2025 | April 30th, 2025 |

Because of the points Rosie made in [her post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396597/165455), we would still set the expectation that we might not deliver the data dump within a couple of days of generation.

### Benefits

- The dumps for any given quarter will accurately reflect *all of* the data from that quarter, up to just before midnight UTC on the last day of the quarter (plus, often, a little bit).
- The Q4 schedule will no longer be affected by the holiday break.

  > <sup>*Mostly a benefit for the Database Reliability Engineering (DBRE) team here, but it also means better predictability for you.*</sup>
- You get one extra set of data in 2024.

### We’d like your feedback

We are proposing this change based on your feedback from Rosie's post, but we want to make sure that there aren't any other considerations we're missing. Let us know if you think shifting the schedule as we've proposed makes as much sense to you as it does to us. We'll review feedback/votes over the next couple of weeks and confirm where we land on or before March 22nd, 2024.

Comment: There is now a 25% chance that you can use [April Fool's Day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/398249/314146) as an excuse for a [missing data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389922/314146)! Smart planning! 

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear communication on something that could have easily been 'assumed' to not need any pre-warning about. Makes me feel involved and included, even if I don't have any other feedback than this!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since this was so well received, we have pushed a new data dump in early April and, for the foreseeable future, we plan to adhere to the schedule outlined in the question.

I've set a reminder to update this answer as each dump is delivered; here's the first update under the new schedule:

| Year/Q | Started | Data through | Delivered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024 "Q0" | March 3rd, 2024 | Feb 29th, 2024 | March 5th, 2024 ✅ |
| 2024 Q1 | April 1st, 2024 <sup>12:28 AM UTC</sup> | March 31st, 2024 | **[April 2nd, 2024](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange)**<sup>1</sup> ✅ <sup>8:32 AM UTC</sup> |

This is *a lot* earlier than you probably anticipated.

#### How'd we do that?

Well, in March, the process looked like this - we'd wait until Sunday, then process each Data Explorer database in sequence. Once Data Explorer was fully refreshed, we'd start the Data Dump process - extract each of the 8 tables to XML, then compress, one database at a time. Finally, we'd start the upload process, which would also upload one file at a time:

[image: Original serial process]

The diagram isn't to scale, but the times are accurate: it took over 70 hours to deliver the data dump for March *once it started* (March 3rd), and it required an additional Data Explorer refresh on a non-Sunday.

#### Since then...

...we have made several improvements to the process:

- Removed the dependency on Data Explorer, so the data dump can start shortly after midnight (UTC) on the first day of the quarter. It no longer waits for (or disrupts in any way) the Data Explorer processing; even if the first day of the quarter happens to also fall on a Sunday, they can now run concurrently.
- Made XML file creation and zipping happen in parallel, meaning uploading can start a lot sooner. We observed more than an 8X improvement here, and Data Explorer should see about a 4X improvement going forward.
- Eliminated ragged end times, so all data ends just before midnight (UTC) at the end of the previous period. This is true for [weekly Data Explorer refreshes as well](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1830732/latest-content-in-stack-overflow).
- Made uploads happen in parallel. I was nervous about throttling and retries but, while we are still a little handcuffed by the upload speed to Internet Archive<sup>3</sup>, the speeds were consistent - even with multiple files uploading at the same time. The upload completed in just over 28 hours, cutting the last upload time almost in half.

All told, almost a 60% reduction in runtime, plus this is measured from the beginning of the quarter, instead of from the quarter's first Sunday at midnight UTC:

[image: New parallel process]

Without question, this was the **fastest delivery in our history**, and we have more improvements planned.

---

#### Minor differences you may have noticed before I did

This is a journey. There were a few minor differences observed by [an anonymous edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/88921) that I can explain and, for the most part, have already fixed:

- **Some data types were rendered incorrectly.** For example, milliseconds were truncated from `datetime` values that didn't have enough precision. Early on, I discovered an inconsistency with `bit` columns rendering as `0`/`1` instead of `True`/`False`, but this one slipped by me.
   → [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- **Minor formatting differences.** The previous version of the output would have two spaces before each `<row` element, and a space before the ending `/>`. In the new format, those spaces were missing. Similarly, `&#xA;` was rendering as `&#x0A;`.
   → [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- **XML files were encoded using UTF-16.** I validated the content of files in the new process, but failed to notice they were encoded incorrectly. While this may not affect everyone, it makes little sense to bloat the files for no reason.
   → [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- **`Posts` actually includes `PostsWithDeleted`.** This again had to do with validation - I spot-checked files for each table, but for sites small enough that I could manually open the files. Those sites I spot checked? Also happened to not have any deleted posts, so they looked exactly like files produced using the old method.
   → [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)
- **XML files are no longer guaranteed to be sorted by `Id`.** This is true. The reason is that we enjoy incredible performance improvements by using parallelism, but we'd throw those gains away (and maybe more!) by forcing a re-sort *after* gathering streams. Presumably people are loading these big files into their own systems, and not perusing multi-GB XML files in Notepad, and those systems should support any subsequent sorting/indexing you need. (In truth, these weren't intentionally sorted by `Id` before; that was just a coincidence. It just happened that the execution plan performed a single-threaded scan against the clustered index, with `Id` as its leading key.)
   → [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Some of these corrections are uploading now. I'll update when complete, and invite you to check my work. :-) Then I'll work on `Posts` / `PostsWithDeleted`.

---

> <sup>1. Most files were actually available on Internet Archive a couple of hours into April 1st.</sup>
> <sup>2. This didn't make either process faster; it just feels a whole lot cleaner.</sup>
> <sup>3. We get about 0.25mb/s, most of the time, with occasional bursts of up to 0.6mb/s. Our largest file, `stackoverflow.com-PostHistory.7z` (369 GB / 39.2 GB compressed), took over 28 hours to upload. While splitting that file up into chunks would allow us to deliver it faster, that would probably break folks, so we'll keep hoping IA will work with us on more efficient file transfer instead.</sup>

Comment: It might make sense to tag your question post as [status-planned], in this case? Up to you, of course :)

Comment: @V2Blast I'm not sure if it should ever sit in status-planned, while it makes sense in English, I think it's more of a holding spot for things that will be completed at some point in the future, and can be reflected as such. No _code_ is changing for this one, so when would it ever transition from status-planned to status-completed? After the next data dump? After the one after that? (Not being combative, just verbalizing my inner conflict. :-))

Comment: Its almost like common sense, logical and better policies are well loved by the community :D. It makes the dumps cover an entire quarter, the exact time of the dumps dosen't 'really' matter - rather that they're regular, *and* we have clear deliverables.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Makes sense :)

Answer (score 117):

Disclaimer: I don't actually use the dumps, so my approval doesn't mean that much.

But, as the author of the comment that sparked this proposal, let me confirm that **this is exactly how I'd expect the data dumps to work.** And the fact that holidays cease to be a problem is certainly a nice bonus.

**Do it!**

That said, I'd like to thank you, twice.
First, thank you for thinking about my comment, and for turning a simple question into a suggestion.
And more importantly, thank you for coming here and discussing the change before applying it!

Comment: +1 especially for the last sentence.  This announcement feels like breath of fresh air.  Simple and noncontroversial as this change is, getting community input on it first is a nice return to how things should be.

Answer (score 21):

Overall, I think the proposal makes sense.

If you start your export on or after the first day of the next quarter, why do you have a minimum date timestamp? I'm not sure how impactful it would be, but would it be beneficial for anyone to have a hard cutoff for what makes it into the data dump? That is, the Q1 data dump should contain no edits or content *after* March 31st, 2024 23:59:59.997. It doesn't matter if you start the process on April 1, April 2, or April 7, the most recent possible data in the dump would be the last moment of March.

If the company is willing to invest resources at some point in the future, this schedule also opens up some flexibility in additional versions of the data dump while still meeting commitments. I think that's a future discussion, but I'd like to see a better XML structure for the data that is more conducive to working with large data sets or non-XML formats like JSON or SQLite. Whatever gets decided, it should be possible to start the process early in the month and do any kind of data translation or massaging and still make end-of-first-month delivery for the prior quarter.

Comment: It pulls data directly (essentially just a table dump) from the source database in SEDE, whenever it runs for that database. SEDE populates from the source database (again, all data) for a given database. We can't do all databases at the same time, nor can we do all the tables in any given database at the same time. And certainly not at 00:00 on April 1st without taking everything down. We can't `WHERE` clauses as they would be far too slow and disruptive (especially for tables that don't have supporting indexes). Same with "cleaning up" the data _after_ collection but before publication.

Comment: As for changing the format, I've mentioned to you before that we couldn't just change the format of the data to suit one consumer when we have to consider _all_ stakeholders. Getting consensus on that change - since it's theoretically the entire world - would be impossible. The only possible way to do what you're asking would be to create a second, separate dump, and, well, I'm not going to comment on the likelihood of that.

Comment: This proposal is _just_ about the schedule. If you have feature requests about the format or the data, those should be separate imho.

Comment: (And I said .997 instead of .999 because the data type is `datetime`, and .997 is the "end" of the day _for that data type_.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand This all makes sense, then. this schedule and commitment opens the door to future feature requests if you commit to "last day of the first month of the following quarter". It also lets you handle things like holidays, vacations, issues, whatever comes up. I like it.

Comment: "If the company is willing to invest resources at some point in the future" ...  I'm guessing there are pretty long odds there.

Comment: @AMtwo I agree with that. It seems unlikely that anything will be invested to improve the dumps and make them more widely useful. But if it does happen, there shouldn't be any interference between any data dump feature requests and meeting the delivery commitments.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Just don't want you holding your breath that there will be any functional changes beyond rescheduling it. That'd be a big 180 change since last March.

Answer (score 18):

### Sounds reasonable

I don't use the data dumps, but have a bit of experience with open data etc. The proposal sounds extremely reasonable to me, and what I would expect from any similar source. I don't think the exact timing of the dump matters much, but it might be helpful to say "It will definitely be up by the end of the following month" or something.

I would have a slight preference for labelling them "Jan-Mar" or similar, rather than "Q1", which always introduces a slight ambiguity (or at least the potential for ambiguity) about whether quarters are numbered from January, or July, etc.

Comment: Thanks! For some additional background, the files aren't currently named or labeled with quarters or months; the metadata on [the archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) just indicates when the most recent upload finished. I was just using _traditional_ calendar Qs in the question above to illustrate what the schedule will look like. I do like the idea in general, since it's a little more accurate than relying on the date of completion (and would travel with the files), but it's a potentially breaking change I'd not want to introduce at the moment.

Comment: I'm not sure a "Jan-Mar" label would make sense. It implies that the dumps contain only the data generated during that time, when each data dump is a full-sized snapshot for a point in time. If I want to be pedantic (Aaron knows how much I do love that), I'd think of it either as "The March dump" (since it has everything through the end of March), or "The April dump" (since it is processed & posted during the month of April), or "The April 7 dump" (since that's the approximate date the snapshot is taken).